# Recorrer una tabla MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla, llamada prueba, en `MySQL`:

[image: Tabla_MySQL]

Ahora me gustaría rescatar dichos datos en `PHP`, pero no consigo aclarar mi idea sobre como es la manera más correcta de hacerlo. Es decir, se supone que yo no debo saber cuantas filas o campos tiene la tabla, si no que en función de lo obtenido, pinte una tabla en PHP con esos datos.

¿Como sería la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "usuario";
$password = "contrasenna";
$bd = "base_datos";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);

if (!$conexion){ 
    die('Error de Conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());    
}   

mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_base_datos";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $fila["campo1_tabla"];
        echo $fila["campo2_tabla"];
        echo $fila["campo3_tabla"];
    }   
} else {
    die("Error: No hay datos en la tabla seleccionada");
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba:

```
$db = new mysqli('host','database_user','database_pass','database_name');
if($db->connect_errno){
   echo $db->connect_error;
}
$result = $db->real_query("Select * From tabla'");
```

En $db configuras la conexión.
Con el if chequeas errores de conexión
Y en la variable $result almacenas el resultado de ejecutar la query.
(La tabla y los datos de configuración tienes que adaptarlos a lo que tengas configurado)

Adaptado de: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-query.php